# swift_dynamiccast taking too much in processing and affecting performance in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, profiling

I am doing a lot of computing in parsing and creating some combination from json data coming from server. The entire process takes a lot of time and majorly I have fixed code related issue but at one place time profiler shows the time taken by one particular call which I cannot figure out.
[image]

I have a lot of casting going on in my processing. It creates a lot of objects of type FlightFare and I create it from a dictionary.

So the conveninece init looks like below, how can I avoid it..?

```
convenience init (dictionary: [String:AnyObject]) {
    self.init()
    refundType = dictionary["rt"] as! String
    if let unwrappedScore = dictionary["r"] as? Double {
        score = unwrappedScore
    }
    if let unwrappedValue = dictionary["t"] as? Int {
        taxes = unwrappedValue
    }
    if let unwrappedValue = dictionary["bf"] as? Int {
        baseFare = unwrappedValue
    }
    if let unwrappedValue = dictionary["f"] as? Int {
        fee = unwrappedValue
    }
    if let unwrappedValue = dictionary["d"] as? Int {
        discount = unwrappedValue
    }
    if let unwrappedValue = dictionary["tf"] as? Int {
        fare = unwrappedValue
    }
    if let unwrappedValue = dictionary["ttf"] as? Int {
        totalFare = unwrappedValue
    }
    if let unwrappedValue = dictionary["hbo"] as? Bool {
        hbo = unwrappedValue
    }
    providerKey = dictionary["pk"] as? String
    hbf = dictionary["hbf"] as? [String]
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason for using [String: AnyObject] instead of [String: Any]? AnyObject does adds some overhead in some test I did here.

Comment: @MarcoPompei No reason as such, was using it in swift 2.3 so kept it that way. I will try it with Any

Comment: If the properties of the object are optional then the `if let...` construct is unnecessary overhead. Simply assign the conditional downcast directly to the property

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like the tax paid when doing things like `value as? String`. You left that node collapsed in the profile, so I can only give general advice on avoiding this: Ensure you aren't repeatedly processing the same data in its raw form. Cast once as part of migrating to a typed intermediate form.

Minimizing type casts is something that the various Swift JSON libraries, like Freddy and SwiftyJSON, attempt to guarantee in their parsing of JSON.

If the structure of your JSON data is similarly uncertain - is this node a string or an object or just null? - then your code runs into and must address this issue at that level, too.

ETA: If the cost of the casts is noticeably charged to your convenience init (you should verify this using the profile), then that method would indeed be a problem. You can avoid it by using a library that parses JSON into a typed representation to begin with, such as Freddy mentioned earlier. This replaces casting in your code with enum case matching within the library.

It's often useful to check the box in the profile options that tells it not to show you framework code, so you can easily see which of your methods that you directly control is taking time. Then you can drill in in the profile to get per-line cost statistics to focus your optimization.

Comment: I have added some more details in the question. And why does casting an object will take so much time....?

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava Often it is not that it takes much time, but that you are doing it so much that even the small time it takes becomes noticeable. Similarly, an Obj-C program can sometimes profile as spending a lot of time in the highly-optimized message-send routine, not because that is terribly slow, but because of a tremendous amount of messaging.

Answer (score 1):

You could write the init() a little differently to separate unwrapping form type casting and gain around 40% speed

```
       for (key,value) in dictionary
       {
          switch key
          {
             case "rt"  : refundType  = value  as! String
             case "r"   : score       = value  as! Double
             case "bf"  : baseFare    = value  as! Int
             case "f"   : fee         = value  as! Int
             case "d"   : discount    = value  as! Int
             case "tf"  : fare        = value  as! Int
             case "ttf" : totalFare   = value  as! Int
             case "hbo" : hbo         = value  as! Bool
             case "pk"  : providerKey = value  as! String
             case "hbf" : hbf         = value  as! [String]
             default : break
          }
       }
```

Or, if the dictionary contains NSNumbers, NSStrings, etc. and you're willing to work with the "NS" types for your internal variable, then there would be no "Dynamic" casting and you'd get a 13x performance boost for that part:

```
       for (key,value) in dictionary
       {
          switch key
          {
             case "rt"  : refundType  = value  as! NSString
             case "r"   : score       = value  as! NSNumber
             case "bf"  : baseFare    = value  as! NSNumber
             case "f"   : fee         = value  as! NSNumber
             case "d"   : discount    = value  as! NSNumber
             case "tf"  : fare        = value  as! NSNumber
             case "ttf" : totalFare   = value  as! NSNumber
             case "hbo" : hbo         = value  as! NSNumber
             case "pk"  : providerKey = value  as! NSString
             case "hbf" : hbf         = value  as! NSArray
             default : break
          }
       }
```

Another strategy you could use is to store the dictionary inside the object without assigning the variables and make them lazy init their values:

For example:

```
  var defaultDict:[String:AnyObject] = [:]
  lazy var score:Double = self.defaultDict["r"]  as? Double ?? 0
  lazy var baseFare:Int = self.defaultDict["bf"] as? Int    ?? 0
  ...

  convenience init (dictionary:[String:AnyObject]) 
  {
    self.init()
    defaultDict = dictionary
  }
```

This would only wok if the init() doesn't reference these variables for some other reasons but, it should bring the object creation time to almost nothing and defer/spread the type cast times by only performing them on actual use of the data.

Comment: Thanks... I will try these out.

Answer (score 0):

First, use `[String: Any]` instead of `[String: AnyObject]` for dictionary in Swift.

Try using [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

SwiftyJSON makes it easy to deal with JSON data in Swift.

> PS: Having so many if-else conditions is not a best practise.

Comment: SwiftyJSON makes it easier for the programmer, but it does this by wrapping NSJSONSerialization's return value in its own tree of structs, and you take a performance hit for this.  If the problem is it's not fast enough at runtime, adding SwiftyJSON will only make it worse.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be checking for a value before assigning.

If all of those values are optional, you can simply assign the optional value `score = dictionary["r"] as? Double` and if there is no value for that key, it will simply assign it as nil.

If you want the variables to have a default value, you can nil coalesce the value `score = dictionary["r"] as? Double ?? 0`

This will cut the number of times you have to access the dictionary in half and also reduce the assignment of temporary variables.